# How to compare two dates in the mongo aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, metabase

We're currently using metabase to analyze our data. I've run into a problem with querying with an aggregation query. I wanted all the documents where date1 is before date2. (I used 3 filters to debug my results, it should be possible to put it in 1 match filter later on)

```
[{
  "$match": {
    "date1": {
      "$exists": true
     }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "date1": 1,
    "date2": 1
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "date1": {
        "$lt": "$date2"
    }
  }
}]
```

I'm always getting no results. Anybody who could help me with the query?

**EDIT:**

The documents looks like this:

```
 { 
   _id: ObjectID,
   date1: ISODate("2016-10-04T08:34:15.041Z"),
   date2: ISODate("2016-10-05T08:34:15.041Z")
   ... some more fields that are not interesting for this query
 }
```

There are around 50k documents in the collection.

Comment: Can you please show a sample document?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `$where` to compare the two date fields.

```
db.collection.find({
    $where : "this.date1 < this.date2"    
});
```

The documents which satisfy the above condition will be present on the result. If any document which doesn't have attributes either `date1` or `date2` will not be present on the result.

**Using aggregate function:-**

**$cmp** can be used to compare the values. `-1` represents the first is less than the second one.

First pipeline is required to eliminate the documents which doesn't contain both `date1` and `date2`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  "$match": {
    "date1": {
      "$exists": true
     },
     "date2": {
      "$exists": true
     }
  }
},
{"$project": {
      "date1":1,
      "date2":1,
      "dateComp": {"$cmp":["$date1","$date2"]}
    }
  },
  {"$match":{"dateComp": -1}}

]);
```

Comment: I'm forced to used the aggregation framework (by Metabase), $where is not a thing in the aggregation framework.